# Does compressing files using zip reduce the file size to upload in google drive?

Tags: upload, dataset, zip, compression

I want to upload a dataset to google drive but it's size is so big. It takes a lot of time and uses a lot of data! Does compressing the dataset to a zip file reduce the size of the file for uploading to google drive?

I searched about reducing file sizes but most of them are about reducing the quality of images or cutting the white space around the pictures. But what can we do with datasets?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a good compression ratio with your data set, then yes, zipping should decrease the upload time. But ... it all depends on the nature of your data set.

For example, if you have files that are already compressed or have images/videos (which already have compression applied) there is a good chance you will either get very little compression or end up with a larger amount of data to upload.

Best thing is to try an experiment with a representative sample of your data set to see if you get a good compression ratio.

The other point to consider is the cost of carrying out the compression. If your sole intention is to decrease the upload time (and not to save on the amount of data stored on Google Drive), your total time cost now becomes the amount of time taken to compress the data plus the upload time. Again - try an experiment with a representative sub-set if your data to see if there is a benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mostly think of data usage. I want to decrease that.